# Error on creating a geometric column in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, geometry, sqlite, column

Many post has been written on this problem but I can't figure out what is my problem here. I want to create a geometric column in a SQLite database to store polygons (geojson format or WKT). I use this code (in Python) to create the a table with columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Registration_areas (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, identifier TEXT, display_name TEXT);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('Registration_areas', 'polygon', 4326, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 'XY');
```

Later in the script, I want to add the areas (var = polygon2) to the column with:

cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Registration_areas (polygon) VALUES (?)''', GeomFromText(polygon2,))

But I get the following error message:

> AddGeometryColumn() error: "UNIQUE constraint failed:
> geometry_columns.f_table_name, geometry_columns.f_geometry_column

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems that you have in the geometry_columns metadata table a row with the same f_table_name + f_geometry_column combination that you try to add again (AddGeometryColumn is doing that in the background). Perhaps it is remaining from your previous trials. Delete the row and try again.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed helped to delete the table and remove rubbish from former trails. Now onto solving the next error which is: sqlite3.IntegrityError: Registration_areas.polygon violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]

Comment: You mention many posts but can you provide links to them, please?

Comment: I just meant that much has been posted about the problem. Just search on it and you'll find various simular posts. But none worked for me. But it was solved thanks to the comment of user30184.